# Can I access headers of all the emails sent within one "Google Apps" domain?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I would like to create a **live visualization** of all the mail communication happening within one "Google Apps" domain used in my organization.

Is there any API which I can use to get a **live callbacks**, or at least some API which I can pull periodically in order to get headers of all the emails sent within the organization?

Comment: Have you seen the **Email Audit API**? http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/audit/docs/1.0/audit_developers_guide_protocol.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Email audit API:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/audit/docs/1.0/audit_developers_guide_protocol.html

Answer (score 0):

Please remember Email Audit API can be used only for lawful purposes in accordance with your Customer Agreement.
There is currently no other way to do what you need.